# Guide Drone using GPS

Tags: gps, drone

I am new to drone building and developing. I am using Cube Orange plus and gps module from company Taoglas. My GPS is fixed few cm above esc. The drone is drifting too much when I am keeping it at a fixed point even when the number of satellite count is 15. I am using it in GPS2 position on on pixhawk board. How can I increase the accuracy of GPS. Any suggestion or links would be helpful that can help me to know how other people do missions based on GPS. I have seen many drones working perfectly using GPS coordinates.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches here. First, keep in mind that even with a high number of satellites, pure GPS will always have some amount of imprecision and that amount is usually measured in meters. The solution to this is to add complementary hardware, and potentially to make use of additional software approaches:

- Use GNSS+RTK: there are many GPS/GNSS modules that add support for RTK, which makes use of the existing satellite connections more effectively for better accuracy (but at additional cost)
- Add an IMU: You could use the GPS to get an absolute position, and then ignore it (except for the occasional localization update). Then, you rely on an IMU to provide information about the relative change in position.
- Kalman filtering: having the ability to accurately model the robot's movement would allow you to compensate for GPS error. This would work especially well with one (or both) of the previously-mentioned approaches, as a kalman filter is very effective for sensor merging.

Keep in mind also that the reason for the drone drift likely has nothing to do with the GPS. It's probably drifting because drones simply drift; if you want to detect and counter this movement you will need something like an IMU.